# How do I create this pivot SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables in our SQL Server 2012 instance:

**tblASSETS**

```
------------------------------------
| ASSETID | ASSETTYPE | NAME       | 
|---------|-----------|------------|
| 1       | A         | Printer A  |
| 2       | A         | Printer B  |
| 3       | A         | Printer C  |
| 4       | B         | Laptop A   |
------------------------------------
```

**tblASSETTYPES**

```
--------------------------------------
| ASSETTYPE | TYPENAME | ICON        |
|-----------|----------|-------------|
| A         | Printer  | Printer.png |
| B         | Laptop   | Laptop.png  |
--------------------------------------
```

**tblASSETCUSTOM**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| CUSTOMID | ASSETID | MAKE | MODEL          | PRINTEDPAGES |
|----------|---------|------|----------------|--------------|
| 1        | 1       | HP   | Laserjet 4v    | 530          |
| 2        | 2       | HP   | Laserjet 4v    | 10000        |
| 3        | 3       | HP   | Officejet 1050 | NULL         |
| 4        | 4       | HP   | Probook 430 G3 | NULL         |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

**tblOIDDATA**

```
---------------------------------------------
| OIDDATAID | ASSETID | LABEL        | DATA |
|-----------|---------|--------------|------|
| 1         | 1       | Black copies | 430  |
| 2         | 1       | Color copies | 110  |
| 3         | 2       | Black copies | 5300 |
| 4         | 2       | Scans        | 450  |
---------------------------------------------
```

I want to build a query which returns all printers and all their details as columns. I already created this QUERY:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(label) 
                    from tblOIDData
                    group by label
                    order by label
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') 

set @query = 'Select * from (   Select Top 1000000 tAT.icon As icon, tat.typename as [ASSET TYPE] ,tA.Name as [ASSET NAME], tac.Model as [DEVICE MODEL], snmp.label as label, TRY_CONVERT(INT, TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), snmp.data)) as PageCount, TA.Printepages as [PRINTED PAGES]   from tblAssets as tA,       tblAssetCustom as tAC,          tsysAssetTypes as tAT,      tblOIDData as SNMP  where tA.AssetType = tAT.AssetType      AND tAT.Typename = ''Printer''      AND tAC.AssetID = tA.AssetID        AND snmp.AssetID = tA.AssetID        ) as s PIVOT (     sum(PageCount)  for [LABEL] IN (' + @cols + ') ) AS pvt'

execute(@query);
```

This almost give the desired result. The only thing I'm facing is that ASSETID 3 (Printer C) is not in the result. Probably because it is not in the tblOIDData table.

How can I include this Asset in my results also?

Comment: Expected Result pls

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). You would want to check what a LEFT JOIN means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `LEFT JOIN` in your dynamic sql.

```
set @query = N'SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  SELECT TOP 1000000
   tAT.icon AS [icon],
   tat.typename AS [ASSET TYPE],
   tA.Name AS [ASSET NAME],
   tac.Model AS [DEVICE MODEL],
   snmp.label AS [label],
   TRY_CONVERT(INT, TRY_CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), snmp.data)) AS [PageCount],
   TA.Printepages AS [PRINTED PAGES]
  FROM tblAssets AS tA
  JOIN tblAssetCustom AS tAC ON tAC.AssetID = tA.AssetID
  JOIN tsysAssetTypes AS tAT ON tAT.AssetType = tA.AssetType
  LEFT JOIN tblOIDData AS SNMP ON snmp.AssetID = tA.AssetID
  WHERE tAT.Typename = ''Printer''
) AS src 
PIVOT
(
  SUM([PageCount])
  FOR [label] IN (' + @cols + N') 
) AS pvt';
```